# Is there a literary term/device for when a narrative repeatedly echoes, mimics or reflects an earlier event?

Tags: terminology

Is there a literary term/device for when a narrative repeatedly echoes, mimics or reflects an earlier event? It is not just a full circle ending, but a series of smaller scenes repeating ('circling' in on itself), but through different characters.

I have just read Khaled Hosseini's *The Kite Runner* and there are several instances of this technique, such as:

- "For you, a thousand times over" (said by Hassan to Amir as children, then adult Amir says this to Hassan's son)
- Hassan threatening to remove Assef's eye with his slingshot and then Hassan's son actually doing it
- Amir receiving an injury and scar to his upper lip, like Hassan's cleft-lip scar from his childhood
- Kamal helping to sexually assault Hassan...and then Kamal being similarly assaulted himself a few years later

Just wondering if there is an actual term for this?

Comment: [parrot-phrasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphrase)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'foreshadowing', for more details and examples see https://literarydevices.net/foreshadowing/

Comment: Thanks, I just thought there might have been a term to identify the 'end result' of the foreshadowing, as in, a term to describe the realization/materialization of the foreshadowed prediction.